# My random computer selection is always scissors

Tags: c#

My assignment is to write the program in such a way that the computer's random selection is displayed before player 2 needs to input their selection. I'm having trouble getting the computer's random selection linking to my if statements. Here's my code so far:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args) {
Random random = new Random();
int computer = random.Next(1, 4);
int player2 = 0;
string response;
string willYouPlayAgian;

Console.Write("Do you want to play Rock, Paper, Scissors? ");
willYouPlayAgian = Console.ReadLine();
willYouPlayAgian = willYouPlayAgian.ToUpper();

while (willYouPlayAgian == "YES") {
if (computer == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player 1 <Compter> selection - Rock" + "\n");
        }
        if (computer == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlayer 1 <Compter> selection - Paper" + "\n");
        }
        if (computer == 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlayer 1 <Compter> selection - Scissors" + "\n");
        }
        Console.Write("Player 2 selection (1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Scissors): ");
        response = Console.ReadLine();
        player2 = int.Parse(response);

        if (computer == player2)
            Console.WriteLine("\nDraw. No winner.");

        else
        if (computer == 1 && player2 == 2)
            Console.WriteLine("\nPaper smothers Rock. Player 2 wins!!!");

        else
        if (computer == 1 && player2 == 3)
            Console.WriteLine("\nRock destroys Scissors. Player 1 wins!!!");

        else
        if (computer == 2 && player2 == 1)
            Console.WriteLine("\nPaper smothers Rock. Player 1 wins!!!");

        else
        if (computer == 2 && player2 == 3)
            Console.WriteLine("\nScissors slices Paper. Player 2 Wins!!!");

        else
        if (computer == 3 && player2 == 1)
            Console.WriteLine("\nRock destroys Scissors. Player 2 wins!!!");

        else
        if (computer == 3 && player2 == 2)
            Console.WriteLine("\nScissors slices Paper. Player 1 wins!!!");

        Console.Write("\nDo you want to play Rock, Paper, Scissors? ");
        willYouPlayAgian = Console.ReadLine();
        willYouPlayAgian = willYouPlayAgian.ToUpper();
    }
```

Comment: Moving the `random.Next()` into the while loop might help.

Comment: How would I insert it in the "while" section?

Comment: Usually you mark the line with your cursor, press ctrl-x, move the cursor down until it is inside the loop and press ctrl-v to insert it there.

Comment: You used a computer before, right?

Comment: I'm sorry I worded my question wrong. Does inserting: int computer = random.Next(1,4) into the loop make the computer chose a number every time the user inputs "YES"?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Why so harsh? He seems to be a beginner. Everybody has begun sometime.

Comment: I'd definitely a beginner. I don't mind harshness as long as I can understand the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Move this line down into the `while`loop:

```
    int computer = random.Next(1, 4);
```

Like this:

```
while (willYouPlayAgian == "YES") 
{ 
    int computer = random.Next(1, 4); 
    if (computer == 1)
    {
```